# English article: a temperature vs temperature

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

I was looking the definition of [temperature](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/temperature) in Merriam-Webster. In count noun section, I noticed a sentence with no article before "temperature".

If a noun is countable, we must use an article (a or the) before it. Is this rule inconsistent?

The sentence is as follows:

> There was a sudden fall/drop in temperature.

A screenshot is below. Look at the second to last example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words denoting measureable quantities can usually be used as uncountable in some contexts.

One such context is after *in*, as a prepositional phrase qualifying another phrase to specify the property:

> a drop in temperature
>
> an increase in size
>
> decreased in number
>
> small in area
>
> great in value

Answer (score 0):

First, in

> A drop in temperature

it's actually noun **drop** what is modified, not **temperature**.

Second, IANAL (I'm not a linguist), but, unlike many other languages, you are generally required to define any common noun, this is how English works, and this is consistent. Using no article is just a syntax which English uses to define nouns in certain ways. E.g., one uses no article with a non-count noun to indicate a thing not known before (where the indefinite article would be used for singular count noun) or referring to the thing in general.

Comment: That's fine, but "temperature" is still a noun. Why doesn't it have an article?